# Add a value to each row from another dataframe of unequal length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following datasets:

dataset1:

```
Class    Value
Yo       53
Save     13
Gold     72
Post     88
```

dataset2:

```
Class   Total_goals
Yo       9
Yo       9
Yo       9
Save     4
Save     4
Gold     7
Gold     7
Gold     7
Gold     7
Post     3
Post     3
```

What I want is to add the `Total_goals` for each class in the `dataset1` from the second dataset.

The expected output will be:

```
Class    Value     Total_goals
Yo       53        9
Save     13        4
Gold     72        7
Post     88        3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `merge(x = dataset1, y = dataset2, all.x = TRUE)` is pretty standard. If you know all Classes from dataset1 are in dataset2, `merge(dataset1, dataset2)`.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [How to join/merge data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061)

Comment: By `add` do you mean you want to add a new column? What is your expected output?

Comment: @RonakShah I added more information.

Comment: then `merge(df1, unique(df2), all.x = TRUE)` ?

Comment: Perhaps `merge(df1, unique(df2[c("Class", "Value")]), all.x = TRUE)` in case there are additional `df2` columns OP isn't mentioning...

Answer (score 0):

Use **cbind**, it will work regardless if you have a matching variable between datasets or not. This does assume that observation levels are the same (i.e., order) between dataframes.

Create your dataframes:

```
dataset1 = data.frame(c("yo","save","gold", "post"),c(53,13,72,88))
colnames(dataset1) = c("Class","Value")

dataset2 = data.frame(c("yo","save","gold", "post"),c(9,4,7,3))
colnames(dataset2) = c("Class","Total_goals")
```

Answer:

```
dataset1 = cbind(dataset1, dataset2$Total_goals)
colnames(dataset1) = c("Class","Value","Total_goals")
```

***Edited to reflect additional info (i.e., duplicate info in the second dataframe), requires matching variable ***

*Solution if dataframes are of unequal length with one containing duplicate data.*

Create your dataframes:

```
dataset1= data.frame(c("yo","save","gold", "post"),c(53,13,72,88))
colnames(dataset1) = c("Class","Value")

dataset2 = data.frame(c("yo","save","gold", 
"post","post","gold"),c(9,4,7,3,3,7))
colnames(dataset2) = c("Class","Total_goals")
```

Answer:

```
dataset1$Total_goal = dataset2[match(dataset1$Class, dataset2$Class),2]
colnames(dataset1) = c("Class","Value","Total_goals")
```

Comment: Makes a very dangerous assumption that the rows are in the same order in both data sets.

Comment: "dangerous" is a bit of an overstatement, but an assumption, yes. As long as the observation levels correspond in both data sets you could use the arrange function from dplyr to sort them into the same order. Edited answer to reflect assumption.

Comment: It doesn't work when there are duplication in the second dataset. I added more information to give you more explanation.

Comment: I appreciate you editing the assumption into your question. I guess I would correct my earlier statement to be a "dangerous recommendation" rather than a "dangerous assumption" -  not stating a strong assumption is dangerous. Now that the assumption is stated, it's a solution that explains when it can be used, so no longer dangerous.

Comment: @Adam Amin , I have edited the answer to include a solution that will fulfill the additional requirements resulting from duplication in the second dataset. Hopefully, this meets your needs.

Comment: @AdamAmin if the edited answer solves your problem, could you please accept it.